# Python | Returns none when doing a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

```
# Let's put it all together. Write code for the function process_madlib, which takes in
```

**# a string "madlib" and returns the string "processed", where each instance of
**# "NOUN" is replaced with a random noun and each instance of "VERB" is** 
**# replaced with a random verb. You're free to change what the random functions**
**# return as verbs or nouns for your own fun, but for submissions keep the code the way it is!****

```
from random import randint

def random_verb():
    random_num = randint(0, 1)
    if random_num == 0:
        return "run"
    else:
        return "kayak"

def random_noun():
    random_num = randint(0,1)
    if random_num == 0:
        return "sofa"
    else:
        return "llama"

def word_transformer(word):
    if word == "NOUN":
        return random_noun()
    elif word == "VERB":
        return random_verb()
    else:
        return word[0]

def process_madlib(text):
    proc =""
    lenght = len("NOUN")
    i=0
    while text[i:i+lenght] !='':
        i +=1
        if text[i:1+lenght] == "NOUN":
            proc= text[i:-1] + word_transformer("NOUN") + text[i+lenght:]
            return proc

    **

**# you may find the built-in len function useful for this quiz
        # documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len**
```

**

```
test_string_1 = "ds NOUN ds"
test_string_2 = "I'm going to VERB VERB to the store and pick up a NOUN or two."
print process_madlib(test_string_1)
print process_madlib(test_string_2)
```

**Always Return none , if i tested it manually and change "i" all look good**

edit : adding code ......

your can read the instruction in the comments

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you saying that your function always returns `None` and you are asking why? Do you want your function to *sometimes* return `None` or *never*?

Comment: `[i:lenght+1]`? should that be `[i:i+lenght]`. Aside: correct spelling is "length"

Comment: Yes,that is the question , my function Suppossed to Change the word NOUN into the string by a real name and The word VERB Also

Comment: For both the strings , `if` never evaluates to true .

Comment: Totally unclear about what you're trying to do, can you add some description or comments? Also, you're never going into the if statement that contains the `return proc` which is why it always returns a `None` by default.

Comment: Try printing the value of `text[i:lenght+1]` each iteration and you shall promptly be enlightened.

Comment: Any reason why your function isn't implemented as `text.replace('NOUN', word_transformer('NOUN'))`?

Comment: I suggest reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips to learn how to debug your code.

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil so to give true , how must i change the `if` condition

Comment: You should look at the functions available for Python's [string class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html). You will find a function there that will make your life much easier.

Comment: @Aran-Fey i follow a python course, and we still not learnig text.replace and this is a Quick test for the 3rd Chapter

Comment: Note that you do not explicitly return anything when the while loop finishes iterating. This is likely the reason you see `None` as the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a few issues with the variable you're using in the loop, specifically you should be using `lenght + i` instead of `lenght + 1`. Also, you're incrementing `i` in the wrong spot.

Here's a version that works:

```
def process_madlib(text):
    proc = ""
    lenght = len("NOUN")
    i = 0
    while text[i:lenght + i] != '':
        if text[i:lenght + i] == "NOUN":
            proc = text[i:-1] + word_transformer("NOUN") + text[i + lenght:]
            return proc
        i += 1
    return text


test_string_1 = "NOUN ds"
test_string_2 = "I'm going to VERB to the store and pick up a NOUN or two."
print(process_madlib(test_string_1))
print(process_madlib(test_string_2))
```

Comment: Another Question if u can, 
if `test_string_1= NOUN ds NOUN` and i want to change NOUN in the two position ? how i do that ?

Comment: Thank u i found the solution 
`def process_madlib(text):
    proc = ""
    lenght = len("NOUN")
    i = 0
    while text[i:lenght + i] != '':
        if text[i:lenght + i] == "NOUN":
            text = text[0:i] + word_transformer("NOUN") + text[i + lenght:]
        i += 1
        
    return text`

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you misspelled "lenght". It should be "length".

Aside from that, what I think you are trying to use is len(i).
Here is the code  in the middle.

```
while text[i:len(text)+1] !='':
    i +=1
    if text[i:len(text)+1] == "NOUN":
        proc= text[i:-1] + word_transformer("NOUN") + text[i+len(text):]
        return proc
```

edited based on Aran-Fey's comment.

Comment: I must have been reading with binoculars on! I missed a few things. I'm glad to see it's been solved.